# jQuery multi and jQuery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: javascript

I'm using drupal 7 and trying to develop some mobile menu effect. I've read a lot of discussion so i've install [jQuery multi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) so my drupal run in back-end jQuery 1.5  and in front-end run jQuery 1.11.3. I've also insert jQuery mobile 1.4.5 to manage mobile touch events but for what i understand this will not execute
thi is my code

`jQuery("#page").on("swipe",function(){ 
    if($(window).width()<=900){
      $("#nice-menu-1").children("li").children("ul").css({display: 'block', visibility: 'visible'});
    }
  })(jq1113)`

It's not a js code problem but a library loading for what i know
i've got some error like this:
`Uncaught TypeError: a.mobile.document.on is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function`
Could someone helo me? thank you

Comment: never run two different type of jquery version instal jquery update module then try it

Comment: i've alredy try, but if i run responsive bartik with jQuery 1.7 page refresh will broke

Comment: How did you add/insert the jQuery mobile 1.4.5 JS file (library)?

Comment: i've add it to html.tpl.php `<script ...></script>` , and it work if i update with jQuery update module to 1.7, but broke drupal core so i'm searching an alternative

Comment: Is your jquery update module the latest version of the module? try with jquery 1.10

Comment: the module is the last version but jQuery 1.10 dont work, also 1.11

Answer (score 0):

I see there are some errors in your code, such as a missing open curly bracket for your if statement and few others.

Try this:

```
(function ($) {

 jQuery.noConflict();
     $(document).ready(function( $ ) {
         $("#page").on("swipe",function(){ 
         if($(window).width()<=900) {
         $("#nice-menu-1").children("li").children("ul").css({"display": "block", "visibility": "visible"});
         }
         });
     });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: the problem it's not the code but jQuery compatibility

Comment: @MicheleS did you give my code a try? won't hurt...

Comment: Yes, i try, but was not that the problem, i've partially solved by adding  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />` This solve js problem but also make my desktop layout similar to mobile and thats not good

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solve by using [jQuery Mobile Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) selecting only mobile events so it reduce collision